# To merge multiple columns into one column and count the repetition of unique values and maintain a separate column for each count in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame like this:

```
                Q1            Q2           Q3               Q4  
0               Bachelor    Postgrad    Postgrad        Masters     
1               Bachelor    Postgrad    Postgrad        Bachelor        
2               Masters     Postgrad    Postgrad        Masters     
3               Bachelor    Bachelor    Bachelor        Masters     
4               Bachelor    NaN NaN     Masters         Masters
...
```

I want to add columns like this:

```
        Q1          Q2         Q3           Q4     Bachelor  Masters  Postgrad 
0   Bachelor    Postgrad    Postgrad    Masters       1        1        2
1   Bachelor    Postgrad    Postgrad    Bachelor      2        0        2
2   Masters     Postgrad    Postgrad    Masters       0        2        2
3   Bachelor    Bachelor    Bachelor    Masters       3        1        0
4   Bachelor      NaN       Masters     Masters       1        1        1
...
```

I tried and able to merge Q1 to Q4 into one column but unable to count the unique values and print these count in the seperate column. Any help to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `get_dummies`

```
s=pd.get_dummies(df,prefix='', prefix_sep='').sum(1,level=0)
s
Out[502]: 
   Bachelor  Masters  Postgrad
0         1        1         2
1         2        0         2
2         0        2         2
3         3        1         0
4         1        2         0
# then using concat 
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
```